# Is there a way to use ASP.net Identity authentication with IIS and HTTPContext?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, httpcontext

I've built a database with efcore using the asp.net identity framework for my users and roles with slight modifications. I would like for a user to connect to my site and be able to log in with their credentials stored in the database. When I'm hosting my Blazor server application on IIS my custom login page shows up and allows the user to enter credentials. However, the httpcontext "user" is null when authenticating. The application obviously runs fine when I'm loading it through visual studio and the problem seems to be just with IIS Authentication.

Comment: You should check the mode of Authentication you have configured in IIS for your site. By default some modes are not enabled. You will need to ensure the mode you are using is enabled and available in your IIS.

Comment: You need to disable anonymous authentication and enable windows authentication.

Comment: The problem I have here is that I'm using the user's email address for their account login. their windows account does not hold this information.

Comment: Can you show the code about login function and how to get the user?

Comment: I was able to get this working using anonymous authentication & without impersonation. The solution was to remove my calls for the user from HTTPContext and get the user from AuthenticationStateProvider instead. Thank all of you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working using anonymous authentication & without impersonation. The solution was to remove my calls for the user from HTTPContext and get the user from AuthenticationStateProvider in Blazor instead.